# absolute positioning align in textarea

Tags: css, textarea

I want to achieve something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/dpnay/. A textarea with some text inside and a name appear right down corner. So far I used absolute positioning to fixed the name text.

My problem is, when I type a long text, the text I typed will cover the name text (unless I scroll down the button). Is there any solution to make the text on textarea didn't cover the name text by using CSS? Because I'm not prepare for using javascript.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to actually put the "signature" text *below* the textarea, but only put the border on the surrounding `div`.  I've made an example from the CSS on your jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dpnay/1/).